# Subring of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ring-theory

In the field of rational numbers, the following subsets are given:
$$
M = \left\{ a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right\} a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\ 
\text{and}\ 
N = \left\{ a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{2}\right\} a,b \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Show that $M$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ and $N$ in NOT a subring of $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried using the following conditions which give us that a subset is a subring of a ring:

$1.\  a+b \in M$ for all $a,b \in M$

$2.\ ab \in M$ for all $a,b \in M$

$3.\ (M,+) \le (\mathbb{R},+)$

But I get stuck on the second one, multiplication. I can't get what is the difference between $\sqrt{17}$ and $\sqrt{7}$. Why the first is a subring, the second - NOT?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Multiply $\frac{1 + \sqrt{a}}{2}$ by itself (where $a$ is either $7$ or $17$) and look at what you get, whether you can see that it is again of the form required. The problem is the $2$ in the denominator. This gives you a constraint.

Comment: @Sasha, In both subsets, I don't get the form I need. I can't get the hint you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2} = 4 + \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$$

$$ \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{7}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{4+\sqrt{7}}{2} = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{2}$$

$4$ is an integer, $\frac{3}{2}$ is not.